# What is the cause of Gangsta.'s drop in animation quality?

Tags: gangsta

What happened to the animation quality in the anime *Gangsta.*? Everything was so detailed and "perfect" to the last detail in the first couple of episodes, but it substantially seemed to drop its quality. Any reason for it?

Comment: 1. company went bankrupt, 2. company went bankrupt, so no

Comment: Well that was a slap in the face. Any reason why they went bankrupt and if they are trying to come back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said @ton.yeung said and as stated in [this article](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/gangsta-samurai-champloo-anime-studio-goes-bankrupt-rip-gangsta-season-2-479790), the studio producing Gangsta, Manglobe Studio, went bankrupt :

> According to animeanime.biz , Manglobe Studio began procedures for bankruptcy on Sept. 29th after months of insolvency. The news of Manglobe Studio’s bankruptcy proceedings wasn’t common knowledge.

Therefore the quality dropped.

For the same reason (obviously), you should not expect a second season or another content related to Gansta, but there can still be a chance that another studio produces it if the Intellectual Proprety of Gangsta get sold.